# Target of offset into import directory unclear

Tags: assembly, struct

During RCE of a piece of code, I have found this:

```
    loc_40244F:
    mov eax, [ebx+20h]
    add ebx, 14h
    test eax, eax
    jnz loc_402397
```

What I know is that ebx points to the import directory structure of the considered PE file.

But when I look at it, I see the following:

```
     Import Directory
     +0 DWORD   OriginalFirstThunk; 
      4 DWORD   TimeDateStamp;
      8 DWORD   ForwarderChain; 
      c DWORD   Name;
     10 DWORD   FirstThunk;
```

So, to which location is the [ebx+20h] expression pointing ?
I hope somebody can help me.

best regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `ebx` really points to an `IMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR`, then [ebx+20h] points to the `name` field of the next `IMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR`.

```
mov eax, [ebx+20h] ;  0x20 = 0x14 + 0xc
```

where 0x14 is `sizeof(IMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR)` and 0x0c is `offsetof(IMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR, Name)`.

Also, remember that the last `IMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR` is always an `IMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR` with all fields set to 0 (according to the [official PE documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463119.aspx)):

> The last directory entry is empty (filled with null values), which
>   indicates the end of the directory table

As noted by @peterferrie, if the `Name` field is NULL/0 then the other field are meaningless so your code is checking if the next `IMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR` is the last, so it can stop processing the array of `IMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR`.

You could surely test this by checking the value in `eax` and comparing it to the value in an hex editor or a PE browsing tool.

Comment: @Neitsa, not all fields set to zero, only the Name field must be zero.  If there's no DLL  named, then the other fields are meaningless and can hold any value.

Comment: @peterferrie Thanks a lot for your clarification, you're right. Although the PE documentation states that the last import descriptor must be all 0, having no Name field indicates the other fields are meaningless, so it's enough to only test the Name field. Edited my answer!